# How can copy only value in excel?

Tags: excel

Hello i want to copy just value not all formula how can i do that in excel VBA.
 Here is my code:

```
Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("F3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("L" & i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can transfer only the values with:

```
Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("L" & i).Value = Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("F3").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

After copying, you can use `PasteSpecial`:

```
Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("F3").Copy
Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("L" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The above will copy your input (whatever it is) and will paste only the value, even if the input was a formula.

Then, it will clear the "cut/copy mode".

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("F3").Copy
Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("L" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```